# How to validate an array in a PHP form?

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to php and was wondering how do I validate the array for the states and where do I place the php code at? I already did the address part but I'm stuck at the states part.

Here is the validation code.

```
if (isset($_POST['contact_info_submitted'])) { // Handle the form.

    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['address']));

}
```

Here is the form code.

```
<li><label for="address-1">Address 1: </label><input type="text" name="address-1" id="address-1" size="25" class="input-size" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['address'])) echo $_POST['address']; ?>" /></li>

<li><label for="state-province">State/Province: </label>
<?php
echo '<select name="state-province" id="state-province">' . "\n";
    foreach($state_options as $option) {
        if ($option == $state) {
            echo '<option value="' . $option . '" selected="selected">' . $option . '</option>' . "\n";
            } else {
              echo '<option value="'. $option . '">' . $option . '</option>'."\n";
            }
        }
            echo '</select>';

?>
</li>
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" class="save-button" />
    <input type="hidden" name="contact_info_submitted" value="true" />
```

Comment: Can you also post the structure of your `form` so the answers we provide can be identical to your code?

Comment: @Anthony Forloney what exactly do you mean? sorry for begin ignorant.

Comment: Agree with Anthony, we need to see more of your page code.  As it is now your validation code doesn't match the field names in your form, so nothing will be validated...

Comment: @SIAcKer: I'm having a difficult time understanding your question. Please edit your question and explain yourself in a bit more detail. Specifically what do you mean by "how do I validate the array for the states"? Are you trying to check that they selected a state?

Comment: @Josh what I was wondering do I have to check to see if the states need to be in code like this `$address = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['address']));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering how to check if someone submitted a valid value for state just check to see if there value they posted is in your array of states. If it's not there it's not valid:

```
if (!in_array($_POST['state-province'], $state_options)) {
    // not valid
}
```

If you're just trying to store in the a database like the other form values it's no different then any text field:

```
if (isset($_POST['contact_info_submitted'])) { // Handle the form.
    $state= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['state-province']);
}
```